# The last logon time of the Administrator user in Windows 7 system is prior to the OS installation date, why?

Tags: windows, forensics, windows-7

What may be the reason behind the fact that in a digital forensics report (FSL report) of a computer's hard disk, the last logon time of the Administrator user in Windows 7 system is prior to the OS installation date?

Does it infer tampering of the Hard disk before examination?

Comment: Has the built-in Administrator account ever been used? Does the last logon time default to e.g. build time in such case?

Comment: @EsaJokinen That may be a case.. is there a way to find the default build in time for Windows 7 ultimate?